# Complex Analysis: Non isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding why for $f(z) = \frac{1}{\text{Sin}(1/z)},~ z= 0$ is a nonisolated singularity and all other z's for which $z = \frac{1}{k\pi} (k = \pm 1, \pm 2,\ldots)$. The explanation from my course book is " Each of the former is isolated, but the singular point z = 0 is not because every annulus inevitably contains at least one singular point ( in fact, an infinite number of them). 
Isn't the closest singularity to $z = 0, \frac{1}{\pi}?$ So, isn't there a region between z>0 and $z< \frac{1}{\pi}$ where it would be analytic?

Comment: I think you forget the definition of being isolated here. Being isolated means every neighborhood misses other points. You found (inevitably) one annulus that contained even one singular point, that's not isolated.

Answer (score 1):

*"Isn't the closest singularity to $z=0$, z=1/\pi?"*

No. $(0<)\,\cdots<\frac{1}{3\pi}<\frac{1}{2\pi}<\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k\pi}=0$. There is no "closest" singularity to $z=0$ (other than $0$ itself).

Comment: Thank you! this is clear now.